# sql query to mysql with where rand limit and or parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$mm6=6;
$chap=8;
            
$rkey = generateRandomString(32);
        
$query = "insert into tbltemp (qchapter, qtype, qmarks, qsession, qlanguage, qclass, question, id, rkey)
          (SELECT qchapter, qtype, qmarks, qsession, qlanguage, qclass, question, id, ?
           FROM questions where qchapter=? and qmarks=?
           ORDER BY RAND() 
           LIMIT 3)";
    
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sii", $rkey,$chap,$mm6);
$stmt->execute();
if ($mysqli->errno) {
    printf("Could not drop table: %s<br />", $mysqli->error);
}
        
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The above PHP code works fine. The problem is I need a more complex SQL command.

```
qmarks=1,2,3,4,5,6
qchapters=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

The user can select multiple marks (like `1,3,6`) and can set a number of questions limit for each mark (like `mark 1 limit 3, mark 2 limit 5, mark 6 limit 10`) and also
user will select multiple chapters from which these questions are to be randomly selected.

Like if the user selects `chapter:1,3,5,7,8` and selects `qmarks=1 limit by 3, qmarks=2 limit by 5, qmarks=6 limit by 10` randomly then the total number of particular mark questions be selected from specified chapters. (PS: Specified chapters are common among different marks but at the same time questions are to be randomly selected from common chapters-in-total).

Thanks.

Comment: To get different limits for each mark, I think you'll need to split it into separate queries.

Comment: yes different sql qeries will solve the problem.